# How to find a functions address to hook/detour in an EXE file?

Tags: c++, c, windows, hook

I drove against a wall again and need your help with some low-level stuff. I already succeeded in hooking exported DLL-Functions ([with this code btw.](https://web.archive.org/web/20100610091602/http://newgre.net/ncodehook)) by injecting them into my target process (e.g. I can easily detour `MessageBoxW` from `user32.dll`). Unfortunately I aim for a different scenario: I have to detour a **function defined inside the executable** I'm injecting my code into. The application is Open-Source so I know everything about the function I'd need for hooking it, but the binary is signed with a certificate so I can not compile my own version. Is it possible to fetch the functions' address at runtime or detour it with another technique? The target is a "normal" 32bit Windows binary btw. nothing special I thought ;)

Yours,
Nefarius

**EDIT:** maybe due to my lame English I was not detailed enough, so here a little sample code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd )
{
    foo();
}

BOOL foo(char* someData)
{
    return printf("%s", someData);
}
```

Now I want to detour the function `foo()` which does not exist in a dynamic library. This is my problem. I don't know how and I'm not sure if this works like I think it does.

**EDIT:** Now I know it is possible, so the important question changed to: how? How do I get the information I need; the functions address?

Comment: Do not put [tags] in the subject line, especially when you are also putting them in the Tags area.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use something like [Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) to set a breakpoint, and edit the assembly after the executable has loaded (and finished checking its certificate). To do it permanently is a bit more challenging, but depending on how sophisticated the certificate check is, you might just be able to bypass that bit of code by replacing it with a `NOP` (no operation).

**EDIT:** If you're running 64-bit Windows, you might have better luck with Microsoft's own [Debugging Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/install64bit.mspx#ECD). I've never used them, so I have no idea how they compare to Ollydbg.

Comment: Oh I do not want to trick the cert away, I don't care about it :-) I just need the (int) return value of a function hard coded into the binary itself. I tried OllyDbg btw. but I have Win7 x64... *starts VBox with XP*

Comment: @Nefaurius: and what's the question? Why don't you just patch it?

Comment: @Ruslik: simple answer: how? I have to admit I have no experience with disassembling/debugging/reversing so I'm pretty headless ATM.

Comment: @Nefarius: this is what happens when you use something without understanding what exactly it does :)

Comment: Sorry but as medic my FASM/i368 and so on skills are not very high and it seems I failed in googling the right terms, it happens once in a half year I have to use some kind of a forum/platform like this. On the other side, instead of telling me something I already know you could give me a little education? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this is for something that is more than a one time debugging jaunt, look into [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), an API for hooking functions.

Comment: I already know how to hook functions and it works. I just don't know how to hook non-dynamic functions defined inside executables.

Comment: @Nefarius: Hooking them is the same. Your only challenge is finding them, as they're not in an export table. But as you said: you've got all information. You can hardcode the function's location, or parse the .MAP file.

Comment: Ok it IS possible, good. So my next challenge will be to fetch the functions address. Do you have a hint for me (link to example, tutorial, whatever?), would appreciate that much. I'm sorry I have no idea how to perform this.

Comment: Do you have access to the PDB files of the executables? If so, you can query the PDB files and get function addresses.

Comment: No I do not have them, just the PE (.exe) file.

Comment: Then you have no reliable way (apart from binary signatures) to find functions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the functions address then insert a jmp at the functions entry point to your procedure and then restore the original proc and then jump back to the original function.

Comment: Check out the patch tool here. Exactly does this:
http://comrade.ownz.com/projects/petools.html

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting, but I still don't know how to detour the function from my injected code. I can hook DLL exported functions without any problems but I need the address of the function, because there is no DLL to hook...

Answer (score 0):

Use EasyHook for that. With that library you can intercept a function with the address.

Comment: I know EasyHook and what it can/does but I *do not have the functions address*!

Comment: You cannot get the address of the function with EasyHook, the address is the function itself (if it is not compiled with linker optimizations). To EasyHook you should pass &foo as address.