# How to find a custom function's address to hook/detour in another running process?

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly, hook

Related to: [How to find a functions address to hook/detour in an EXE file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317465/how-to-find-a-functions-address-to-hook-detour-in-an-exe-file)

I have to detour a function defined inside the executable I'm injecting my code into. The application is Open-Source so I know everything about the function I'd need for hooking it.

In the accepted answer to that question, it says to hook some low level windows api functions first to get the address of the actual function I want to hook, question is, which windows API function should I hook?

Answer (score 1):

Choose an API inside your target EXE that get called first when it runs. Load it to [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de) and trace until you find one.

Comment: You mean to find the offset of the function from the base of the PE and then handle any rebase of it?

Comment: Yes, or search that function using a byte pattern.

Comment: Any way to find the offset programmatically and automatically from the process that is already running? Otherwise for each version, the offset might change and I have to manually do that each time

Comment: If your target is not stable and function's address is changed from time to time, I think there's only way is handle each version separately.